# office documents won't open with quicklook

Tags: ios, ms-office, docx, doc, quicklook

I've created 2 test applications:

In the one the documents are included into the bundle and *can* be opened by using the quick look controller. 
In the other app, the documents are downloaded. When I try to open the files the quick-look controller simply shows a message saying an error occurred. Strangely it will open downloaded PDF documents without any problems.

I suspect it has something to do with headers and mime-types, but I'm not sure on this. Would anyone know what the reason could be that downloaded .doc or .docx documents won't open and local documents will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with saving the downloaded files. At first I was writing the data to a filepath URL. This saved the data to the right location, but the type of file wasn't recognized anymore.

The solution was to use the default FileManager to save the file.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:data attributes:nil];
```